# Program to find from where the program is called

Tags: python, java, linux, bash, executable-jar

The requirement is very simple, I want to write a simple hello world program or anything so the program knows about its execution parent. For eg.

Since I am from a Java background I will give a Java example. I want to write a jar that runs and outputs the following:

Running from command line:

```
$ java -jar myjar.jar
Hello world called from bash
```

but when running from myscript.sh:

```
$ sh myscript.sh
Hello world called from myscript.sh
```

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# runs the jar
java -jar myjar.jar
```

Now, I am language agnostic regarding this so any language/library that can help me achieve this is welcome, the only requirement is it should be able to be called from a bash script and should recognize the script that calls it.

Every idea is welcomed.

Comment: The variable `PPID` contains the pid from the parent process. You can then use `ps`  to find out the command line to be used to invoke your parent process. This is not the same as knowing the execution parent (because the command line could tell a lie, or because symlinks are involved, or because you don't know how the PATH resolves in the parent process), but for most cases, this is probably good enough. Give it a try.

Comment: @user1934428: IIUC OP wants to get parent process in their Java program

Comment: In this case, I don't understand why this is also tagged bash and Python. If the OP wants to know how to get the PPID in one of those languages, this should be expressed explicitly. For instance, for Java this has been discussed [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-parent-process-of-the-process-api-in-java-9).

Comment: @user1934428 tagged bash, python, java because I am language agnostic here, if it can be done through any means, it is welcomed.

Comment: Sure, but every language has a different way to fetch the PPID, so you will get different answers depending on the language. Therefore it makes more sense to ask several questions, one for each language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in python like this:

Basically it should be same, be it any programming language. You need to get the parent process ID and name of the process associated with it. If you use Java program, I guess you can achieve the same there also.

I named the python script as test.py and shell script as test.sh

*test.py*

```
import os
import psutil

ppid = os.getppid()
process_name = psutil.Process(ppid).name()

print("Parent process ID of current process is:", ppid)
print("The parent process name is: ", process_name)
```

*test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

python test.py
```

*Output:*

```
python test.py
('Parent process ID of current process is:', 14866)
('The parent process name is: ', 'bash')


./test.sh
('Parent process ID of current process is:', 15382)
('The parent process name is: ', 'test.sh')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the caller and the command with all its arguments as a string by passing the `$PPID` variable to `ps`, example:

```
printf "Called from: %s\n" "$(ps -o args= $PPID)"
```

Sample output:

```
Called from: /bin/bash ./caller.sh
```

For more output options see the [ps man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps)